# Installing maven dependencies for JBPM casefile services

Tags: maven, jbpm

I am trying to install the dependencies for org.jbpm:jbpm-case-mgmt-api and org.jbpm:jbpm-services-api to access ServiceRegistry, Case Service, CaseFileInstance, etc. to access case data but I just can't seem to get my pom.xml correct.  I am using version 7.48.0.Final-redhat-00004. Including

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbpm-case-mgmt</artifactId>
        <version>7.48.0.Final-redhat-00004</version>        
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbpm-case-mgmt-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.48.0.Final-redhat-00004</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbpm-case-mgmt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>7.48.0.Final-redhat-00004</version>
      </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-user-bom-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.kie}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbpm-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.kie}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.kie}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>      
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-internal</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.kie}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>      
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbpm-services-api</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.kie}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>      
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbpm-case-mgmt-api</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.kie}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbpm-case-mgmt-cmmn</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.kie}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
```

as dependencies still leave all my casefile API references as missing (and the above seems like it is specifying these libraries twice!)  What dependencies do I need to add to my pom.xml?

The property version.org.kie is defined as 7.48.0.Final-redhat-00004.

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to include

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbpm-document</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jbpm</groupId>
  <artifactId>jbpm-case-mgmt-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

with the corresponding version (if you don't use dependencyManagement section).

Try and paste the exception you obtain